# How to register specific column(field) in models.py file in admin

Tags: python, django

this is my model i like to register Just single field 'tag' in admin.py file separately from my original Content model.

```
class Content(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # show=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    show=models.ForeignKey(Show,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sponsor_link=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    content_file=models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shows_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    publish_now = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    schedule_release = models.DateField(null=True)
    expiration = models.DateField(null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've used

```
tagset = Content.objects.all()

def content_register():
    for a in tagset:
        admin.site.register(a.tag)

content_register()
```

But i get this error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

can anyone help me here

Comment: you have to do like this ``admin.site.register(Content)``

Comment: Yes but i just want to add 'tag' field in admin.py not anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Content


class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tag',)
    list_display_links = ('tag',)


admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)
```

see official [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for more information